# Magento 2 , unable to place order with stored credit cards

Tags: magento2, checkout, onepage-checkout, place-order, stripe

Place order button is not working when i add new billing address and click place order 
using stripe stored credit card , i m trying to debug and check for the place order function.
as each payment method has its own view model and place order button i've tried to a log in it but still not able to track/find the issue.
any thoughts where i can i find this "place order" function or any solution ? (when i click "place order it send ajax requests but doesn't redirect or place order , check image[image]) Answers & interest are appreciated.

Comment: Get any error in console?

Comment: No , there are no error in console ,  when i click "place order it send ajax requests but doesn't redirect or place order ,pls check image.